# how to get scan-build to run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, analyzer

Hi I found [this](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/scan-build-better-than-build-analyze.html) very helpful post where he describes how to implement scan-build a better analyzing tool then the one xcode comes with.

These are the instructions to get started:

```
1. Download scan-build
2. Just unpack it into any directory and add that directory to your PATH
3. Open a Terminal and cd to your project’s root directory
4. Run scan-build and view results
```

But I don't understand the second point what does "add that directory to your PATH" mean
and how do I do that ?

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/folder/where/you/downloaded/the/analyser
```

Incidentally, scan-build is the *same* analyser that Xcode comes with.

Comment: where do I put this ? this guys says in his blog it is not and scan-build finds a lot more! is that wrong ?